# Stateful components loosing state on query refetch

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Is it correct that stateful components loose their state on a `Query` component refetch? Do I have to use Apollo client state for all components inside `Query` components?

Here is a little demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/qxx6jk3yz9 (increase count and then refetch - count will be reset)

Here is the main part of the demo's code:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
  <div className="App">
    <Query query={GET_ALL_FILMS}>
      {({ data, loading, refetch }) => {
        if (loading) return "Loading...";

        return <Counter refetch={refetch} />;
      }}
    </Query>
  </div>
</ApolloProvider>
```

Comment: Including a demo is super helpful, so thank you! It's generally also a good idea to include at least some of the relevant code in your question, even if you include a link to a demo. If the demo link ever ends up dead, we want to make sure your question is still relevant to future readers.

Comment: ok, thank you for your edit. I will keep it in mind for my next question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conditional inside the `Query` component's render function, namely

```
if (loading) return "Loading...";
```

The `loading` state is updated not just on the initial load, but anytime refetch is called. That means when you hit refetch, only `Loading...` is rendered and the entire `Counter` component is unmounted. When the loading state changes back to `false`, the `Counter` component is rendered again, but because this is a new component, it starts off with a fresh state.

If you comment out the conditional, you'll see the App behave as you expected.

There's a variety of ways you could approach this problem. Here's three:

- Manage the state through Apollo, Redux or some other state management library
- Lift the state up so that it's stored in the `Query` component's parent component, and then pass the state down to your `Counter` component, along with a function to mutate it.
- Instead of not rendering the Counter component, just hide it, for example by setting `display` to `none`.